# Getting rid of the history, secretly stored in the windows 10 registry

Tags: registry, windows-10

I don't know if this was true in windows 7, but I found that all the websites I ever visited, was stored in Windows 10 registry under

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8dhgmset8bbwe\Children\001\Internet Explorer\DOMStorage\<website>
```

Three questions

- Is this a new feature in windows 10?
- How do I delete this log?
- How do I disable this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug.
Even deleting the browsing history is keeping the list of domains visited.

Report it via the Windows Feedback app. There's already something related under 'Microsoft Edge and IE / Microsoft Edge - Settings' that I've added a reference to this question on.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably only true when you use Microsoft Edge?
I cannot test this since I do not have Edge on my computer, but you can remove permissions in the `InternetExplorer` registry key by right clicking on the key and clicking "Permissions".

Unclick "Allow" for Full Control for `SYSTEM` and `CREATOR OWNER`, hopefully that should disable the logging.